# OpenGL ES 2.0 render to texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I'm trying to render to a texture using OpenGL ES 2.0, but I can't seem to make it work.

This is how I proceed:

```
    struct RenderTexture
    {
        GLuint framebuffer;
        GLuint tex;
        GLint old_fbo;


        RenderTexture(GLuint width, GLuint height)
        {
            glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &old_fbo);

            glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
            glGenTextures(1, &tex);

            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 
                         width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, 
                         GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                                   tex, 0);

            glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLuint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
            if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
                cout << status << endl; // this is not called
            }

            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, old_fbo);
        }

        void begin()
        {
            glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &old_fbo);
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        }

        void end()
        {
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, old_fbo);
        }
    };
```

But when I try drawing on it and using the resulting texture, the texture is drawn as totally black.

If I just don't wrap the drawing code in `render_tex->begin();` and `render_tex->end();`, everything draws correctly, leading me to believe that the problem is isolated to the code above.

Comment: Ahh yeah, textures need to be a power of two. Nothing to see here...

Comment: Did you ever get this bit of code working?

Comment: Unfortunately I get a clear screen when I try, and I dont get how to fix this "power of two" thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been a while, but as I wrote in the comments, be sure you're initializing a power of 2 texture.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the texture is not bound before trying to render into it. Even if not using texturing at all, trying to render into a currently bound texture may invoke undefined behaviour and just not work.

You should actually call `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)` after the `glTexImage2D` in your `RenderTexture` constructor, or maybe restore the previously bound texture, like you do with the FBO. Just make sure the `tex` is not bound when you render into the FBO.

Comment: I added `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);` in the constructor, right after checking the FBO status. It's probably good practice, but it did not change the result.

Comment: @sharvey And you also don't accidentally bind the texture when you render into the FBO?

Comment: The texture is in fact no bound when drawing to the FBO. Not only is TEXTURE_2D bound to zero at the end of the constructor, another texture is bound later on during the actual drawing.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same problem as u do. Try to add

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

right after `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);` and black square have to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to make use of `glActiveTexture`. I recommend you to call `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+tex);` before each `glBindTexture(tex);`, which will save you a lot of headaches when you use more than one texture. I guess the error is in the code you use for drawing the texture on the screen.